# Ambiguity in function overloading in java

Tags: java

As return type does not play any role in function overloading,and compiler only check the unique existence of only those part of code which is used at calling time..

Then why not this code contain error

```
class Temp{
  Temp(){
    System.out.println("Default Constructor");
  }
  void Temp(){
    S.o.p("HEll"); 
  }
  public static void main(String a[]){
    new Temp();
  }
}
```

Output=Default constructor...//
I am shocked there is NO COMPILE TIME ERROR as copiler only check only those part of code which is used at calling time ,means compiler need to check only unique existence of Temp() and there is no unique existence of Temp().

Kindly elaborate

Comment: There's no overloading here. One is constructor and other is a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `void Temp()` is a method and you should invoke it on instance. It is allowed to declare method with name of the class but invocation is different. You can call only constructor with `new` operator.

You can read more about Constructor in [JLS#8.8. Constructor Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8)

> Constructors are never invoked by method invocation expressions (§15.12).

**Major difference here you should note is constructor do not have return types and definition of overloading includes return types.**

Answer (score 1):

[Constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) don't require a return type and `void Temp()` will be treated as method not constructor.

When you call `void Temp();`, constructor with no arguments will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

One is a constructor, the other is not.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler distinguishes between method and constructor call using keyword `new`. Only constructor can be after `new` keyword.

Comment: But compiler will go for a check that Temp() exist or not,If we will not add Temp() compiler will do the same,And if  talking about method overloading concept still go for unique existence  of Temp()...I am aware about this fact that compiler distinguishes between method and constructor..My doubt is how it is being done in case of constructor as well as in method overloading condition

Answer (score 0):

Classes, methods, and fields reside in different namespaces. Compiler always can determine what construct is used, and easily differentiates `new Temp()` (class) from `o.Temp()` (method) and `o.Temp` (field).

Comment: Yes, we may write horrors like Type Type = new Type();

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse, you may avoid this usage:

[image: See the line above "Apply" button]
See the line above "Apply" button